# RVM Installation Issues Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, ruby, rvm, rubygems

I have Elementary OS installed on my PC and have installed RVM through the terminal.

However, when I type this `type rvm | head -1`, instead of "rvm is a function", I get `rvm is hashed (/home/edson/.rvm/bin/rvm)`.

Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 0):

As bash manual page says, "is hashed" means that the command is stored in a hash table, to be used in a more efficient way, because that prevents it from having to search $PATH every time you type the same command.

You could check hash table with "hash" command, and you could purge entries with "hash -d command".

Comment: But why does it not show _as a function,_ the way rvm is usually supposed to show up?

Comment: If you use "type -p", still shows as hashed?